# SQL checking between two dates not returning any results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query -

```
WITH get as 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT patient, start, thru_dt, 
        CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, -30, thru_dt), 112) AS DATE) as thru_dt_minus_30,
        cd,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patient ORDER BY thru_dt) AS row_rank
        FROM mytable
        where patient = '1861'
    ) a 
    WHERE row_rank = 1 
    AND cd = '30'
)
SELECT *
FROM get 
LEFT JOIN tb1 ON get.patient = tb1.patient 
LEFT JOIN tb2 ON get.patient = tb2.patient
LEFT JOIN tb3 ON get.patient = tb3.patient
LEFT JOIN tb4 ON get.patient = tb4.patient
LEFT JOIN tb5 ON get.patient = tb5.patient
LEFT JOIN tb6 ON get.patient = tb6.patient
WHERE thru_dt_minus_30 >= tb2.d1 AND thru_dt_minus_30 <= tb2.d2
```

If I exclude the `where` clause of this query, I get 27 records back for this patient in 1 sec. But when I include the `where` clause, the query keeps running without returning any results. It has been 40 mins since I ran this and my query is still running. What am I missing?

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
Patient  thru_dt_minus30   tb2.d1        tb2.d2
1861     2020-01-30        2020-01-01    2020-01-15
1861     2020-01-30        2020-01-01    2020-01-31
1861     2020-01-30        NULL          NULL
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
Patient  thru_dt_minus30   tb2.d1        tb2.d2
1861     2020-01-30        2020-01-01    2020-01-31
```

I would only expect the second row in the output because the date in  `thru_dt_minus30` is the only date between `tb2.d1` and `tb2.d2`.

Comment: @DaleK Updated.

Comment: Are they stored using date datatypes, or varchar?

Comment: They are dates. That is why I am casting `thru_dt_minus30` to a date.

Comment: Need to see an execution plan to advise why its running so slow. However there is a trick which may well solve the problem, instead of using a CTE, store the output of the CTE into a temp table and then run the second part of your query against the temp table. That should work fine with only 27 rows.

Comment: I have to cast it to a varchar first because the thru_dt is in varchar. If I do not cast it and try to do `thru_dt - 30 days`, it gives me the wrong result.

Comment: In that case you are doing it wrong, because the first function call is `DATEADD(DAY, -30, thru_dt)` i.e. you are adding days to it while it is still a varchar.

Comment: Ok changed that. The query is still not returning. @DaleK

Comment: Ok I changed the where clause to tb3. `tb2` was NULL but `tb3` wasn't and it returned the result in a second. I would expect it to return 0 rows for `tb2` though which it is still not doing. @DaleK

Comment: It looks like whenever the value of d1 and d2 is NULL, the query is not finishing. @DaleK

Comment: Try handling that explicitly then e.g. `where tb2.d1 is not null and and tb2.d2 is not nul and thru_dt_minus_30 >= tb2.d1 and thru_dt_minus_30 <= tb2.d2`

Comment: @DaleK That isn't working but if I change the above statement to query `tb3` and `tb5`, it works. Those tables that have records and are not NULL.

Comment: Try the temp table solution instead of a CTE then.

Comment: Ok I will try the temp table. Why do you think the temp table will work?  @DaleK

Comment: Because it forces SQL Server to create 2 separate query plans... and if you are only expecting 27 rows from the initial query the second query with the where clause should run fast. A CTE generates a single query plan, which can be quite convoluted.

Comment: What happens when you remove all other joins but keep `get`, `tb1`, `tb2` with same `where`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider moving the `WHERE` condition to `ON` clause to filter needed resultset by time before the other joins. Also, consider even `BETWEEN` for code compactness.

```sql
...
FROM [get] 
LEFT JOIN tb1 
      ON [get].patient = tb1.patient 
LEFT JOIN tb2 
      ON [get].patient = tb2.patient 
      AND [get].thru_dt_minus_30 BETWEEN tb2.d1 AND tb2.d2 
LEFT JOIN tb3 
      ON [get].patient = tb3.patient 
LEFT JOIN tb4 
      ON [get].patient = tb4.patient 
LEFT JOIN tb5 
      ON [get].patient = tb5.patient 
LEFT JOIN tb6 
      ON [get].patient = tb6.patient
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for me. What do you mean by "filter needed resultset by time" though?

Comment: I meant you filter your time logic, (`[get].thru_dt_minus_30 BETWEEN tb2.d1 AND tb2.d2`) on the particular `JOIN` rather than the end with `WHERE`.